# Attaching events to Session OnStart and OnEnd using HttpModules

Tags: asp.net, session, events, httpmodule

Does anyone know a clean way of adding events to Session's OnStart and OnEnd events using an HttpModule (without touching the Global.asax file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void Init(HttpApplication app)
{
   var ssm = app.Modules["Session"] as SessionStateModule;
   ssm.Start += Foo;
   ssm.End += Bar;
}
```

Comment: Google brings up this solution in the comments of this blog: http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/06/12/146356.aspx but the author describes it as "something of a nightmare". Why would that be? Just a little concerned that this could cause issues.

Comment: Just found this answer and also wonder whether this is the right things to do, after somebosy has indicated it's "something of a nightmare"?

Answer (score 2):

Session OnStart behavior can be emulated by - in one of your HttpModule´s request events - checking if **HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession** is set to true.

However there's one pitfall! If not a value is set in the Session object, the next request will have a positive value as IsNewSession. So once you possitively checked for IsNewSession you should set any value in a Session object.